# UIView animation ignores duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios5, uiview

I'm trying to perform an animation from within a UIView subclass, on one of its subviews.

The animation duration **ignores** any value I try to set it to, and just performs on a permanent duration of ~2 secs. 
The `finished` flag returns with True.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    img.frame = newFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"result: %d", finished);
}];
```

When I'm using the old way, it works fine:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
img.frame = newIconRectFinal;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I copied your code into a UIView subclass, and animated the frame of an image view -- it worked as it should, so I don't think the problem is in the code you posted.

Comment: Do you have another animation block that is running at the same time / encapsulates this block?

Comment: @Wain, you're right! I did accidentally encapsulated 2 animations. It's weird though that the old animation style worked fine, isn't it?

Comment: @Wain, anyway please right your comment as an answer so I can give you the credit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have the animation encapsulated inside another animate and its duration is being used for both of the animations.

Comment: if this is the case what should we do?

Comment: change the nesting, preferably by design, worst case by pushing the 'inner' animation so it's created on the next iteration of the run loop

Comment: but sir I am running it in cellForRowAtIndexPath and thats the only animation I have there

Comment: Then the view you're trying to animate isn't on screen yet, look at the display delegate methods or scroll delegate methods (and perhaps ask a new question with specific details of the issue)

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code before start the animation write this single line code.

***[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];***

see below the code it will work. Now it will not ignore duration

```
-(void)doAnimation
 {
   view2=(UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
   UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{       
    view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 30, 1024,768);
    view2.alpha=1.0       
     completion:^(BOOL finished){  
     view2.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768);
       view2.alpha=0.0 
    [weakSelf doAnimation];  
      }];
   }
```